# Is there any explanation (other than storing plaintext) for case-insensitive passwords?

Tags: passwords, password-management, password-policy

I've come across a few organisations stating that passwords are case-insensitive. Obviously this is ridiculous, and a gigantic red flag from a security point of view.

Is there ***any*** explanation for why a password might be case-insensitive, other than them storing the passwords in plaintext?

Comment: The same reason why people sometimes still use LANMAN hashes, legacy... Not that it's an excuse btw :)

Comment: At the end of the day the number of possible passwords are not increased by that many when a password is case-insensitive.  There are many organizations, Blizzard Entertainment for example, that implement case-insensitive passwords and do not store their user's passwords in plaintext.  At the end of the day when you are talking about your typical password which is secure enough to even be used, the length of time it would take to brute force that account, is high enough where it is not even a concern.  `PaSsWoRd` is no more secure then `password` or `PASSWORD`

Comment: @Ramhound Actually `PaSsWoRd` is more secure as attacker is less likely to make such attempt then `password`. It's just not secure enough to use it.

Comment: @Ramhound - really? An 8 character password that allows digits and letters has ((26 + 10) ^ 8) == 2,821,109,907,456  possible combinations, whereas case sensitivity doubles the number of possible letters: ((26 * 2 + 10) ^ 8) == 218,340,105,584,896 combinations. That's 77 times more combinations to try in brute forcing, and that number grows with password length. Of course, a longer password is better, and you should allow special characters, too. But disallowing capitals is clearly bad.

Comment: Why would "storing the passwords in plaintext" be an explanation for (or even related to) having case-insensitive passwords?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only reasons I know of are either legacy or performance based (with the latter really being a legacy issue too)

- Some old password code removed case to suit the limited platform it was written for,
- and some to just limit the complexity of the code.

Both **useless** reasons which should have no applicability these days.

Answer (score 16):

I agree with Emil that it's a question of usability. Making passwords case-insensitive puts an end to the common user error of entering the password with caps lock on.

Also, a case-insensitive password doesn't have to be stored in plaintext, it can simply be converted to lower case before it is hashed. The only security concern with having case-insensitive passwords is that it lowers password complexity, but this can be mitigated by requiring longer passwords or passphrases.

Comment: +1 one for the counter example to plain text requirement.

Comment: "_puts an end to the common user error of entering the password with caps lock on._" It does not on the typical Windows where CAP LOCK actually is a **shift** (not capital) lock. It only helps for `[alpha]`.

Comment: I've had (older) members of my website make this mistake so many times *"My password doesn't work!"* that I was considering forcing one case behind the scenes to avoid it. Ugh.

Answer (score 10):

One possible reason could be usability. We have all seen how some users have difficulties correctly typing their password, due to cap locks or wrong case.

Having case insensitive passwords increases the success of login in.

Comment: I would have said this was a probable reason. IT departments pandering to the lesser tech savvy user (and thus saving time in support calls). I can understand this being used internally, but on a public network it is obviously unwise.

Comment: I favor usability in the correct context. (Not my banking, though!) As long as the website implements fairly decent password requirements and some form of invalid password logic (say after 5-10 attempts) that bans the IP address, I don't see the issue. These days, you got to worry more about DDNS attacks than say a brute-force or dictionary attack. Hackers don't typically try the front door anyway.

Comment: "_We have all seen how some users have difficulties correctly typing their password, due to cap locks_" Windows has a "CAPLOCKS is activated" message when entering account password, it is much more user friendly approach.

Comment: "_some form of invalid password logic (say after 5-10 attempts) that bans the IP address_" when an ISP uses carrier wide NAT with a few IP addresses for all customers, this means blocking a fraction of all ISP clients.

Comment: @curiousguy, the windows approach is more secure, not more usable.

Comment: @Emil I think it is both secure and usable.

Answer (score 7):

By flattening case, you allow people to enter passwords on a traditional phone keypad.  I have seen more than one example of a bank that does this so that customers can have the same password at the website, as they do over the phone.

ie.

password:  joe123

on-phone: 563123

This is obviously a significant compromise in security, and limits the password to 24 of the 26 letters in an English alphabet, if you assume [really old phones](http://technabob.com/blog/2006/12/16/the-rotary-dial-mobile-phone/).

In some early systems, in the days of 7-bit connections, if you gave your username in all uppercase, it assumed you couldn't do mixed case, and flattened your password during authentication.